# Apps Script Authenticated UrlFetchApp Request to Google Maps Using Cookies

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cookies, google-apps-script, session-cookies

I recently found out that you can request the following URL while authenticated with Google session cookies:

`https://www.google.com/maps/preview/locationsharing/read?authuser=0&hl=fr&gl=fr&pb=`

This returns a kind-of-sort-of-JSON object with all of your Location Sharing data. There is no official API for this data.

How could I make this request in Google Apps Script? I know I need to copy one of the cookies in my Google Maps storage section from the web tools, and maybe put it into a function something like:

```
function refreshLocation() {
  var params = {
    'headers': {
      'Cookie': "the-cookie-i-copied"
    }
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com/maps/preview/locationsharing/read?authuser=0&hl=fr&gl=fr&pb=", params)
}
```

but I'm unclear which cookie to look for and use.

---

**Edit**: I've made progress! I was able to watch the network request waterfall in Developer Tools while just waiting for [google.com/maps](https://google.com/maps) to load, and I found the actual request that the page makes to that URL above. When inspecting that request, I found a very long string in the "Request Cookie" section that then worked when copied and pasted into the code block above!

If anyone has any ideas on how to automate the refreshing of that Cookie, that would be swell.

---

**EDIT 2**: Okay. From reverse-engineering the very long Cookie string of an authenticated Google Maps session, I've found that you only need to include four Cookie parameters using `UrlFetchApp`: `SID`, `HSID`, `SSID`, and `SAPISID`. If you include a Cookie string with those four parameters, it will return data. Something like:

```
params = {
  "headers": {
    "Cookie": "SID=bdoFXEuLJQ5KmEQtC3OEzcqmL1uPGRF32T8AhSZ45XPfQ2toQCCk3khFwXHgRh1t6ciwJ6.; HSID=ENOHYuxdAxl0Ejemw; SSID=dZHZ3C8m0-jgLvcYm; SAPISID=Sdt1GD3GtaimggF5L/76Wi5OZhuwWu2W6V;"
  }
};

var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com/maps/preview/locationsharing/read?authuser=0&hl=fr&gl=fr&pb=", params).getContentText();
```

Anyone have any idea how to turn a OAuthToken into these parts of a session cookie?

Comment: Appscript cannot read things that reside in your machine/browser, since it runs on the server. You'll need some sort of greasemonkey script running in your browser that will fetch such cookie and then put it somewhere your script can fetch, like a file in your Google drive. This looks like a big hassle to use apps script in this use-case. You're better off using something else and using Google Sheets API if you want the results back to a sheet.

Comment: Probably dumb... but, Maybe send the oAuth access Token as 'Bearer' in headers? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()

Comment: I know that Apps Script can't read from my browser itself, but I was wondering if I could make and refresh my own session cookie from the server-side.

Comment: @I'-'I Excellent idea. I gave that a shot (`{ "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }`), no dice :/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL This method is deprecated now.... But ,If possible, this is  probably your best shot...  Send username & password in a POST(read curl docs and experiment with urlFetch- I'm probably sending you ona wild goose chase) ..receive the headers from  HTMLResponse from urlFetch -> it'll contain your SID and stuff, if successful...